# How to prevent frequently visited websites' history get deleted as I cleared the browsing history?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I just cleared 15,000 browsing history from Google Chrome, that much histories slow down the browser a lot. After I cleared it, it runs faster, but the search bar doesn't do the shortcut trick anymore (E.g: When I type in letter *f*, it lists out websites like *facebook.com*), I know it's because the history is gone, is it any way to prevent frequently visited websites (or manually selected) get deleted as I cleared the browsing history?

Comment: But the "frequently visited websites" _are_ calculated based on your history...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution:

> 1. Clear Browing History
> 2. Visit all the websites you think you will visit in the future.
> 3. Close the browser.
> 4. Go to *"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"*, right click on a file called *History*, select *properties*, and check *Read-only*.
> 5. This will prevent Google Chrome storing browsing history, so I don't need to clear browsing history anymore.

It still writing down the history though, but it won't save the URL typed in the address bar for the prediction service. That's fine for me now, because that's the main issue to me.